# Get a char from NSString and convert to int

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber, foundation

In C# I can convert any char from my string to integer in the following manner

```
intS="123123";
int i = 3;
Convert.ToInt32( intS[i].ToString());
```

What is the shortest equivalent of this code in Objective-C ?

The shortest one line code I've seen is

```
[NSNumber numberWithChar:[intS characterAtIndex:(i)]]
```

Comment: seems some Mac fans trying to vote down the question which demonstrates shortcomings of obj-c

Comment: "What have you you tried?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: No matter what I tried. I can not include too much code in this simple question. Have you heard about KISS principle?

Comment: Well, thanks for making the edit, the question seems improved; +1 it is now!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Many interesting proposals, here.

This is what I believe yields the implementation closest to your original snippet:

```
NSString *string = @"123123";
NSUInteger i = 3;
NSString *singleCharSubstring = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
NSInteger result = [singleCharSubstring integerValue];
NSLog(@"Result: %ld", (long)result);
```

Naturally, there is more than one way to obtain what you are after.

However, As you notice yourself, Objective-C has its shortcomings. One of them is that it does not try to replicate C functionality, for the simple reason that Objective-C already *is* C. So maybe you'd be better off just doing what you want in plain C:

```
NSString *string = @"123123";

char *cstring = [string UTF8String];
int i = 3;
int result = cstring[i] - '0';
NSLog(@"Result: %d", result);
```

Comment: I would actually prefer this method to mine simply because it demonstrates the use of the NSMakeRange function to extract specific characters from the string. +1.

Comment: All these methods are longer than mine with NSNumber, but ok. Let's say we have the shortest answer.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't explicitly have to be a `char`. Here is one way of doing it :)

```
NSString *test = @"12345";
NSString *number = [test substringToIndex:1];
int num = [number intValue];

NSLog(@"%d", num);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a third option, you can use [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this too:

```
NSString *string = @"12345";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
int result = 0;
if ([scanner scanInt:&result]) {
    NSLog(@"String contains %i", result);
} else {
    // Unable to scan an integer from the string
}
```