# How can I decode an NSString using the A1Z26 cipher?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cryptography, equivalent

I'm trying to decode an using the A1Z26 cipher (which is just a=1, b=2, ..., z=26). The input text is separated by hyphens, like this:

```
-8-16-2-7-8-5-
```

I have JavaScript which solves this problem, but I cannot seem to get a version working in Objective C

```
function a1z26Cipher(inputString) {
    var outputString = "";
    var splitString = inputString.split(/(\W| )/);
    for (var i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
        var n = splitString[i];
        if (n >= 1 && n <= 26) outputString += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(n, 10) + 64);
        else outputString += n.replace("-", "");
    }
    return outputString;
}
```

What would equivalent code in Objective C look like?

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I think you would find this post helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193611/get-a-char-from-nsstring-and-convert-to-int Have a good one!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Objective C this can be done as follows:

```
-(NSString *)decode:(NSString *)input {
    NSArray<NSString *> *components = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (NSString *component in components) {
        if (component.length == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        char charValue = (char) [component intValue];
        [output appendFormat:@"%c", charValue + ('a' - 1)];
    }
    return [NSString stringWithString:output];
}
```

Note that this assumes the input already has the correct format. It will accept strings of the form `"--42-df-w---wf"` happily.

EDIT: If there are multiple possible separators (e.g. hyphen and space), you can use `NSCharacterSet`:

```
-(NSString *)decode:(NSString *)input {
    NSCharacterSet *separatorSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"- "];
    NSArray<NSString *> *components = [input componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separatorSet];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: Sorry, corrected a bug. Was just converting the ASCII before.

Comment: Still doesn't work you shouldn't get the char by the separated string int value , you should add that value to ('a' - 1)

Comment: Can you explain how it's not working? Running it on my system works fine. If you look at the following line, `('a' - 1)` is added there.

Comment: char charValue = (char) ([component intValue] + ('a' - 1)); is the fix cuz I take the int value (from 1 to 26) and then add it to the value of a - 1  to get the char at that position, e.g 1 will become (1+ ('a' - 1 ))which is a

Comment: The addition is already being performed on the following line: `[output appendFormat:@"%c", charValue + ('a' - 1)];`.

Comment: Oh that didn't work for some reason in the beginning , also is it possible to declare more separators like space etc.

Comment: Edited the answer, see above.